# Preamble too large

Tags: preamble

I have a question about the preamble. In my LaTeX documents the preamble is often too big (about 1000 lines): is there a method to create a subfile (e.g. New File) in which to write the preamble and then call it in main.tex?

If my question is unclear, you can think about Overleaf's `\subfile{chapter/Introduction}`-command (e.g. the one in templates for writing a thesis).

In this subfile I would like to put all the packages and all my `\newcommand`s, `\tikzset`s, etc.

Is what I ask possible?

Thanks all in advance

Comment: You mean `\documentclass{...} \input{preamble} \begin{document}...`?

Comment: Maybe, I don't have the slightest idea, that is why I posted the question. Using the command you suggest, how would an MWE look like? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents ... and start using \input{ } ...

Comment: You need to make a `preamble.tex` file. Then in your main document write `\input{preamble}` (before `\begin{document}`)

Comment: Thx, just solved. Thx all you again

Comment: You can also name your custom macros file with the extension `.sty`, which can be `\usepackage`d. For example, I have a file `my-tikz.sty`, and I can use `\usepackage{my-tikz}`.

Comment: Thx Teddy van Jerry. Your comment is very useful for me

Comment: 1000 lines sounds much too long. My preambles are never so long. Check if you can clean up and remove something.

Comment: you could  put in a separate file but I would guess your preamble is 950 lines too long

Comment: My preamble is 915 lines long, but will soon exceed 1000 lines. Could I create one **sub-subfile** for `\newcommand`s, another for `\tikzset`s and another for other purposes and then put it all in the `subfile{preamble}`?